# tmux window list - what is the text in "quotes"

Tags: tmux

If I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>- <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd> I see a list of `tmux` windows:

```
(0)  0: NAME_HERE  "▒▒`▒"
(1)  1: NAME_HERE "abcdef123456"
```

If I give a `tmux` window a name with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd>, it appears in the NAME_HERE part.

What is the text in quotes? I presume some kind of description?

I curl'd a binary file to the console by accident, and ended up with that junk above, so I'm fairly sure there's some control character sequence that allows this to be edited, I just don't know what it's called and haven't found anything obvious like "tmux window description" searches turning up anything useful/likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information is the pane status text. It is dinamically generated based on many parameters(last command executed, directory change...). What is important here is that, after Tmux 2.3 you can set up that name manually by using the following command:

```
printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'pane title'
```

This could be a workaround to your issue.

**Source:** [GitHub - Add support for tmux 2.3's pane status text #384](https://github.com/tmux-python/tmuxp/issues/384)

---

Now, about the garbage you are seeing at the pane status it could be an issue similar the below, where some escape gabage is causing this to create problemas at your pane status.

**Source 2:** [GitHub - send-keys -R causes garbage unicode output #43](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/43)